# Revert lead conversion

Tags: lead-conversion

I accidently converted a lead. Is there any way to undo this operation. I have seen one solution which says create another lead using data from contact and account which was created after lead conversion and delete these account and contact.

Is there any solution other than this.

Comment: There is no automated possible way to "un-convert" a Lead once it is converted into Account, Contact and Opportunity.

This can only be done by manual editing.

Answer (score 5):

There is no OOB way to solve this for a variety of reasons

- The Lead Conversion can execute triggers on the converted-to-objects. These triggers could create new objects or even do callouts to external systems
- The Lead Conversion can also fire workflows and process builder flows that in turn send emails, do outbound messaging, create related objects, use Apex invocable methods, etc.

As the scope of related, downstream changes is hence unbounded, there is no way SFDC can roll this back.

Consider yourself lucky that you realized you made the mistake and clean it up manually by recreating the `Lead` from the Account+Contact data and deleting the converted-to `Account` and `Contact`. If emails were sent out, you may ned to manually construct an email apologizing for the errant user action

Answer (score 0):

You can unconvert an opportunity using this app:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4HnnEAF

It will create a button in your opp. view to unconvert your opp.

It's very useful and works well!

Answer (score -1):

What I did is just deleted Account to which Lead was converted.
Another addition is to remove ConvertedAccountId and ConvertedContactId values in Lead object. (you can do this either by Apex or Workbench)